# COUNT both http and https Facebook sharing

Tags: php, facebook, sharing

Hi all this is very wired question, I want to add both **`http`** and **`https`** Facebook sharing count.

Is this possible ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure whether I understand your question - feel free to clarify and I'll update my answer.

I'm assuming your Share config looks like the following:

[image: Facebook share config]

If so, the "Step 1" already has `https://` / `http://` already replaced with `//` - this will resolve to the corresponding protocol.

You could update the code in the second section, replacing `https://` with `//` and you should be good to go.

If I'm not understanding the question properly, feel free to clarify.

Cheers

Edit: or do you mean showing the shares from both your `http://` and `https://` domains? Ideally, if you have a `https://` domain, you'll be redirecting all traffic to that anyway in your server config.